# Create MKV from BDMV with saving chaptering

Tags: ffmpeg

How to create MKV from BDMV/BDRemux with saving information about chapters **using FFmpeg**?

I can easily make MKV from `STREAM/00000.m2ts`, but the chapters information will be lost. The chapters information is in `PLAYLIST/00000.mpls`. 
Another question:
How to add the information from `.mpls` to MKV?

MakeMKV can do it, but FFmpeg not? It does not look like a hard feature.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently ffmpeg [does not support Blu-ray chapters directly](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3953).

[MKVToolNix](https://mkvtoolnix.download/), however, supports reading chapters from the playlist file. If you want to do a full remux (using only `mkvmerge` from MKVToolNix), you can use the following command:

```
mkvmerge /path/to/BDMV/PLAYLIST/00000.mpls -o /path/to/remux.mkv
```

The created Matroska file includes chapter metadata.

If you only need the chapters you can create a “dummy” Matroska file that only contains the chapters:

```
mkvmerge -A -D -S /path/to/BDMV/PLAYLIST/00000.mpls -o /path/to/chapters.mkv
```

The `-A`, `-D` and `-S` switches tell `mkvmerge` not to copy the audio, video and subtitle tracks.

You can then use the created file with ffmpeg or extract the chapters as XML with `mkvextract` (also from MKVToolNix):

```
mkvextract /path/to/chapters.mkv chapters /path/to/chapters.xml
```